# Spring Security does not redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-security

I'm implementing a web application using Spring 4 and Tomcat 7.

I run the application on Tomcat with SSL certificate and it works fine, but I want to force any HTTP request to redirect to its HTTPS request.

I've searched for Spring Security and add some configuration as below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class CoreSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .portMapper()
                .http(80).mapsTo(443);
    }
}
```

But it seems not working correctly and no redirect is done by Spring Security.

Is there any problem with this configuration?

Comment: You can try adding `http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity()` to tell the client they need to use HTTPS.

Comment: @ngreen I add redirect config to tomcat web.xml and it works fine. Any way, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Steps to Configure SSL on Tomcat and Setup Auto Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS](http://www.journaldev.com/160/steps-to-configure-ssl-on-tomcat-and-setup-auto-redirect-from-http-to-https), by adding redirect config to Tomcat's `web.xml`, Tomcat does redirect.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>My Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Hi @BabakBehzadi, this solution works, thanks! If you understood why the HttpSecurity port mapper does not work(as per your question), please share, because it does not work for me either and i would love to understand why.